# Is there any elementary embedding characterization for $\Pi_{1}^{1}$ - reflecting cardinals?

Tags: set-theory, large-cardinals

Similar to one of the characterizations of weakly compact cardinals, a $\Pi_{1}^{1}$ - reflecting cardinal is defined as follows:

> A cardinal $\kappa$ is $\Pi_{1}^{1}$ - reflecting if $\kappa$ is inaccessible and for every $A\subseteq V_{\kappa}$ *definable* over $V_{\kappa}$ (with parameters) and for every $\Pi_{1}^{1}$ - sentence $\Phi$, such that $(V_{\kappa}, \in, A)\models \Phi$ there is an $\alpha <\kappa$ such that $(V_{\alpha}, \in, A\cap V_{\alpha})\models \Phi$.

Note that the notion of a $\Pi_{1}^{1}$ - reflecting cardinal, is much weaker than $\Pi_{1}^{1}$ - indescribable (equivalently weakly compact) because in the definition of a $\Pi_{1}^{1}$ - reflecting cardinal, the set $A$ is *definable* over $V_{\kappa}$ using some parameters while in weakly compact cardinals this condition is not necessary.

As weakly compact cardinal has some well-known characterizations defined by elementary embeddings, it is natural to ask whether one can find such a characterization for $\Pi_{1}^{1}$ - reflecting cardinals or not?

Comment: It sounds like you are talking about a $\Pi^1_1$-indescribable cardinal. I think a cardinal $\kappa$ is $\Pi^1_1$-reflecting if it is inaccessible and $V_\kappa\prec_{\Pi_1} V$.

Comment: @VictoriaGitman Please note that in my definition the set $A$ is *definable* over $V_{\kappa}$ while in indescribable cardinals there is no such a condition on $A$. Anyway it is well-known that weakly compact cardinals are identical to $\Pi_{1}^{1}$ - indescribable cardinals. .

Comment: They also called definable weakly compact cardinals. See [Small Definably-large Cardinals](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F3-7643-7692-9_3) where many equivalences of such cardinals are given. For your specific question definable weakly compact embeddings could be the answer.